# How to popup chat window using node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am working on node.js and began to create a chat application I have built it successfully but the problem is that I want the chat window should be open when the client click on the name of the sender(who sent the message to the client). 
I will show you the example what I have done till now.

[image]

Here you can see that the chat box is already open but I want it should open when a user is selected from "List of users" and the content of chat box should be replaced whenever a new user is selected and previous content should be removed. 
Here is my index.html code :

```
<div class="col-md-4 user-list">
            <h2>List of Users</h2>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" 
                    ng-repeat="user in userList"
                    ng-class="{ 'active' : user.id == selectedUser.uid}"
                    ng-click = seletedUser(user.id,user.userName);
                    ng-style="{
                        'cursor': user.id === socketId ? 'not-allowed' :'pointer'
                    }"
                    >
                    <span id='{{user.id}}' >{{ user.id === socketId ? 'You': user.userName }}</span>
                    <span id='{{user.id + "notify"}}' style="color:black; opacity:0.5; font:2px; padding:5px; visibility:hidden;"> {{'typing...'}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>

            </div>
</div>
            <div class="container" id="messages">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> {{'Chat -' + selectedUser.uname}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul class="chat col-md-7"
                                ng-repeat = "message in messages" 
                                ng-style ="{'float':message.fromid == socketId ? 'left' : 'right'}">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="clearfix">
                                            <div class="direct-chat-text"
                                            ng-style = "{'background-color': message.fromid == socketId ? '#d9edf7' : '#62f3bc'}"
                                            >
                                                {{message.msg}}

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <br></br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <textarea elastic type="text" class="form-control custom-control" ng-model='message' ng-keyup="keyup()" ng-keydown="keydown()" ng-change="change()" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendMsg()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

If you would require any other information related to code please comment.
As I am newbie to node.js so help me to solve my problem.

**UPDATE**
My script.js code which have sufficient details:

```
app.controller('app', ($scope,$timeout,socket) => {

$scope.socketId = null;
$scope.selectedUser ={ uid: null, uname: null};
$scope.messages = [];
$scope.msgData = null;
$scope.userList = [];
var TypeTimer;                
var TypingInterval = 1000;


$scope.username = window.prompt('Enter Your Name'); 
if ($scope.username === '') {
    window.location.reload();

}


$scope.seletedUser = (id,name) => {
    if(id === $scope.socketId)
    {
        alert("Can't message to yourself.")
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.selectedUser =
        {
            uid: id,
            uname: name
        }
    }
};
    $scope.sendMsg = () => {
//  const keyCode = $event.which || $event.keyCode; 

    if ($scope.message !== null && $scope.message !== '' && $scope.selectedUser.uid !== null) {     
        socket.emit('getMsg',{
            toid : $scope.selectedUser.uid,
            fromid: $scope.socketId,
            msg : $scope.message,
            name : $scope.username
        });
        $timeout.cancel(TypeTimer);
        TypeTimer=$timeout( function(){
        socket.emit('getTypingNotify',{
        toid : $scope.selectedUser.uid,
        fromid: $scope.socketId,
        msg:"hidden"
           });
          });   
        $scope.message =  null;
        console.log($scope.selectedUser.uid);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("enter a message or select a User to send message");
    }
};



socket.emit('username',$scope.username);

socket.on('userList', (userList,socketId) => {
    if($scope.socketId === null){
        $scope.socketId = socketId;
    }
    $scope.userList = userList;
});     


socket.on('exit', (userList) => {
    $scope.userList = userList;
});

socket.on('setMsg',(data) => {
        document.getElementById(data.fromid+'notify').style.visibility= data.msg;

      });       

socket.on('sendMsg', (data) => {
    //console.log('send');
    $scope.messages.push(data);
});
```

Comment: please show your angular file

Comment: What you do in the UI to display things like this has absolutely nothing to do with server side. Angular runs in browser, node runs on server. Also this is not a *"How to"* tutorial site

Comment: I know this is not a tutorial site . And I have already mention that if you require code I will provide it .

Comment: I just want to know where I should put my id=messages parent div element with its children and subchildren so that it would appear when I click on user . For ex: I should create a new directive or put this somewhere in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching some tutorials and questions(on StackOverflow) I found a way and going to share with you all.

I created a directory name "open" and an attribute visible of this "open" directive to show and hide the dialog.

```
app.directive('open',function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>{{"Chat -" + selectedUser.uname}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div ppp-chat></div>
                                <br></br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <textarea msd-elastic type="text" class="form-control custom-control" ng-model="message" ng-keyup="keyup()" ng-keydown="keydown()" ng-change="change()" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendMsg()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`,
        replace:true,
        scope:false,
        link: function postLink(scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.visible,function(value){
                if(value == true)
                {
                    $(element).show();
                }
                else
                    $(element).hide();
            });
            $(element).on('show.bs.open',function() {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                });
            });
            $(element).on('hidden.bs.open',function() {
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                });
            });
        }   
    };
```

});

And a method in controller to toggle the chat window(hide or  show)

```
$scope.toggleChat = () => {
    $scope.showChat = false;
    $scope.showChat = !$scope.showChat;
};
```

this toggleChat is used to change the value of showChat scope variable that is used to turn on(off) the visibility of chat box by alterating the showChat value as true or false.

In html I have replaced my id="messages" element( with its child and subchild) with

```
<open visible="showChat">
            </open>
```

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is u want to show a pop up on click of a button or some text box u can use angular bootstarp model as shown here

```
"https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview"
```

and control the close and open in angularjs contoller and send the chat details too server side